# Embedded chatbot widget and colliding CSS classes

Tags: html, css

I have a chatbot widget that is written in Svelte and which can be embedded in a web page.

The widget can for example display button components:

```html
<div class="button tooltip svelte-77xh8o">...</div>
```

The styles are defined in the corresponding Svelte-Button-component:

```css
.button.svelte-77xh8o.svelte-77xh8o { ... }
.button.tooltip.svelte-77xh8o.svelte-77xh8o { ... }
```

So far so good. Unfortunately, the web page that embeds the widget also loads a `styles.css` file that defines a `.tooltip` class. Now the styles of `.tooltip` are also applied to the widget buttons.

What is an elegant solution to avoid applying the `.tooltip` styles from `styles.css` to the widget buttons? (The `styles.css` is loaded externally and cannot be edited by me.)

Comment: Can you edit the widget and rename the `.tooltip` class there?

Comment: I have already thought of that. I could, but would like to avoid it in case there is a more elegant solution.